# Does this notation produce a scalar?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

In Blum, Hopcroft and Kannan's *"Foundations of Data Science"* they discuss the Perceptron Algorithm (p. 111). In the proof it says:

> We will keep track of two quantities, **w***<sup>T</sup>***w**<sup>*</sup> and |**w**|<sup>2</sup>. Each update increases **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> by at least 1.
>
> (**w** + **x<sub>i</sub>***l<sub>i</sub>*)<sup>*T*</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> = **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> + **x<sub>i</sub>**<sup>T</sup>*l<sub>i</sub>***w**<sup>*</sup> ≥ **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> + 1

The implication seems that both **w***<sup>T</sup>***w**<sup>*</sup> and |**w**|<sup>2</sup> are scalar values. I interpret |**w**|<sup>2</sup> as the dot product of **w** with itself, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419887/squaring-a-vector/1419890). However **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> (and similar uses of transpose throughout the proof) does not make sense to me, as I don't see how it can produce a scalar value.

My reasoning is as follows:

The vector of weights **w** is a row vector.
The vector of weights **w**<sup>*</sup>, which assumes the "if" condition of the theorem, is also a row vector.

A transposed row vector, multiplied by a row vector, is a column vector multiplied by a row vector, which produces a matrix the size of the column multiplied by the length of the row.

For example, let:

$$\mathbf{w} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{w}^* = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then:

$$\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}^* = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & 6\\4 & 8 & 12\\6 & 12 & 18 \end{bmatrix}$$

My assumption is that "≥ **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> + 1" means "equal to or larger than the sum of two scalars, **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> + 1". Hence **w**<sup>T</sup>**w**<sup>*</sup> should be a scalar.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your source works with row vectors ? Because if $\mathbf{w}$ is a column vector, it becomes clear that $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}^*$ is scalar.

Comment: Thanks @Fabien. True, I wondered about that - I can't be 100% sure. I'm more familiar with the programmatic implementation, where the weight vector is typically a row vector, same as the input feature vector **x**_i. The nearest hints I can find in the text are: "The task is to find a *d*-dimensional vector **w**" and "the weight vector **w** will be a linear combination of the **x**_i". To me this translates to row vectors, but I could be wrong.

Comment: They stick to mathematics' conventions in this book, saying explicitly "row vectors" for probabilities and "column vectors" for space vectors. They don't say anything about $\mathbf{w}$, but I think they consider it as a space vector, and thus a column vector.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I will follow up on that. My aim is to link the mathematical approach to the programmatic implementation, which is why I find it counterintuitive, coming from the applied side - however it might still be compatible. Elsewhere I noticed that the proof assumes the following to be equivalent: $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}^* = \,\mid\mathbf{w}\mid\mid\mathbf{w}^*\mid$ and $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w} = \,\mid\mathbf{w}\mid^{2}$. So my reading of it is that $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{w}^*$ is the same as the inner product of $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w}^*$.

Comment: That sounds like the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|v\cdot w| \leq |v||w|$, with equality iff $\lambda v = \mu w$ for some scalars $\lambda,\mu$.